# Why do we get 1 if we cube the 3rd root of unity?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I was told that $e^{\frac{2 i\pi k}{n}} = \omega_n^{k}$

then we were told that if we were solving a polynomial of which there are 3 solutions. $\omega^3 = 1$ because it is the third root of unity.

What does it mean to be the third root of unity? And how is $\omega^3 = 1$ derived?

Comment: This is the definition, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Answer (score 3):

Solving the equation :

$$x^3=1$$ you must get three roots, since it is polynomial of degree 3. Therefore :

$$x^3-1=0 \implies (x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$$ 
$$\implies x=1 ~\text{or}~ x^2+x+1=0$$

Now the solutions of the equation $$x^2+x+1=0$$

Are $$x=\frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt 3}{2}$$

Which are called as $\omega$ and $\omega ^2$

(If you square any of the two imaginary roots, you will get another one I.e. $(\color{blue}{\omega})^2=\color{blue}{\omega^2}$ and $(\color{blue}{\omega^2})^2=\omega^4=\omega^3 \cdot \omega=\color{blue}{\omega}$  )